# Problem in statics in applications in engineering mechanics at coursera

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, free-body-diagram, statics

in the first image the instructor neglected the reactions at point d and e while he was drawing an fbd to the whole structure ... Shouldn't we give attention to the reactions at d and e while we are solving the equilibrium equations??

[image: Here is the first image from applications in mechanical engineering]

in this second image , the instructor assumed that the pin reaction at point d has only a reaction in the x direction though it doesn't permit movements upwards and sidewards , so it has to have a reaction in the y axis as well ?
Also , he neglected the 120N force at the point B ...

[image: Here is the second image]

Comment: Hmm i am sorry .. maybe you are right . How to move it??

Comment: I have just flagged it for migration. In general you do this by the following operations "Flagging > Closing > Off-Topic > Migration > Physics.SE"

Comment: The second image is on Google Drive and requires a login. Could you please take both these images, reduce their size by appropriate cropping and reduction in resolution, and then post them as part of the question? If you look at the toolbar while editing the question, you'll see an icon for doing this. Stackexchange questions are supposed to be self-contained as much as possible.

Comment: Ok thank you , I think now they are contained

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the pin forces at *D* and *E* because they are internal to the system. When doing an overall FBD, only include externally applied forces and reactions.

In this case the force at *B* and reactions at *A* and *C* are needed only.

For your second question, member *DE* is a two force member (only two connections). This means that along forces along *DE* are allowed (which is horizontal).

This is the reason that $D_x$ is considered only.

PS. GaTech alumni here.

Comment: I don't know how can I treat a force as an external force or as an internal force to the system .. so can you please explain that to me ? Also I don't understand why aren't there any forces in the vertical direction on DE ?? Finally when he draw the diagram for BA he neglected the 150 N force! Sorry I am too lost and can't get those things from the instructor

Comment: I hope you help me thanks for your kindness

Comment: Consider all three rods as part of the same body. Only forces acting between the body and the environment need to be considered. That means points _A_, _B_, and _C_.

Comment: If there ware side forces on _DE_ (acting vertically) let's say on one end, then an equal and opposite force would be needed on the other and to keep the member from moving. But two equal and opposite forces a distance apart create a torque which cannot be opposed by anything (such as a 3rd connection). So the  **only** possible loading on members with 2 connections is a force in-line with those two connections.